# Window based application or Navigation based application

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

i'm starting developing a new iPhone application, the interfaces that i will implement contains a lot of that shaft :

[image]

I have actually two question, what the suitable template to use? Window or Navigation based application? 
Second question : in the Navigation Based Application, the first view that appears when i run the app is the one that contains a UITableView as below, can i replace it by an Image (UIImageView)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Navigation based app is what you are looking for here. And yes, you can replace the UITableView with a UIImageView. I tend to start any project with a Window based project, and here's a quick way of doing it using window based project:

- Create a window based project
- Create you first view controller
- Then in you application delegate, in the method applicationDidFinishLaunching, create a navigation controller, set it's root view controller to the view controller you created in the last step, and set the mac controller as the root view controller of the window. Here's a sample code:

  FirstVC firstVC = [[FirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:@"nil"];

  UINavigationConroller *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];

  [[self window] setRootViewController:firstVC];

If you want to use a Navigation based project, then simply at the initWithRootViewController, remove the view controller set up by the template and set it to your own view controller.

Comment: Hi PragaOnce, thanx a lot for that, i have one more question, does the Window Based Application template still have that Shaft above?? thanx in advance :)

Comment: Glad to help. Nop. That's part of the navigation controller, so once you you set the nav controller as root vc of winnow, it will be there.

Comment: But it does exist in the window based template, isn't it ?